# How to initally hide searchbar in Navigation controller on iOS 13?

Tags: uikit, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller, uinavigationitem, ios13

In iOS 13 the behavior has changed so that by default when Navigation controller appears the search bar is visible (when `UISearchController` is assigned to a `navigationItem.searchController`). Some system apps appear with the search bar hidden (you need to swipe down for it to appear), but I don't see any specific property that would allow this. How to achieve this - maybe there is some property or some method to do that?

Comment: Navigation controllers don't have search bars by default so please update your question with details about what you are doing to get a search bar in place.

Comment: @rmaddy I will but just wandering if you really have no idea what I am doing as showing search bar in navigation controller is a standard procedure since iOS 11.

Comment: There are different solutions so it is important for you to be clear on what exactly it is that you are doing. Your edit is far from enough detail.

Comment: @rmaddy as some people (possibly you) downvote, please answer what you are missing. Did you try to reproduce the problem with the description above. I can, and I don't see how implementation of searchbar controller would influence this as even the simplest one works.

Comment: This question seems clear to me. Navigation Items with search controllers assigned (thus with a search bar) behave differently in iOS 13 - they are visible on load. The obvious ideas (setting a content offset of the table, or programatically scrolling the table to a the first row) don't work.

Answer (score 9):

Via experimentation, I have discovered that if you delay assigning the search controller to the navigation item until `viewWillLayoutSubviews` or `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, the search controller starts out hidden, as desired. However, this if you do this on iOS 12 or earlier, the search controller will not be revealed when scrolling down.

I ended up doing the following with a messy version check, which is working for me:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    searchController = /* make search controller... */

    if #available(iOS 13, *) {
        // Attaching the search controller at this time on iOS 13 results in the
        // search bar being initially visible, so assign it later
    }
    else {
        navigationItem.searchController = searchController
    }
}

override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    navigationItem.searchController = searchController
}
```

Comment: This sounded promising and I've upvoted, but at least for me it doesn't have any effect, so possibly it works only in some cases.

Comment: @IvanIčin darn :(

Comment: The original post is the exact problem I was having and this fixes it for me. Thank you @bunnyhero

Comment: Didn't fix it for me - is this the initial VC of your app btw or some other VC?

Comment: @royherma This isn't the initial VC of my app.

Comment: I've got a Tab bar Controller (initial vc) -> root vc is Nav Controller with a UIViewController that has a UITableView and I'm not able to hide the search bar during load..tried everything :( @bunnyhero

Comment: If it doesn't work for you in `viewWillLayoutSubviews` or `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, try doing it in `viewDidAppear` instead. That worked for me!

Answer (score 6):

To start with a hidden `searchBar`, simply set the `navigationItem.searchController` property ***after*** your table view (or collection view) has been populated with data.

Comment: None of these answers work for me. With this approach it either is not there at all until I switch to a different view and then back or it is already there. It seams a bit random and one time it just popped in, not smooth at all. I get the feeling they don't want to hide it. In this tutorial I'm following he said you 'might' have to pull down to see it, but when I run his example, its already there. https://www.raywenderlich.com/4363809-uisearchcontroller-tutorial-getting-started Must be dependant on the iOS version

Answer (score 3):

Inspired by [bunnyhero's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58262046/7235585) I put the code responsible for setting the `UISearchController` in `navigationItem` inside the viewDidAppear method. Seems to be working every time for me on iOS 14/15

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    if navigationItem.searchController == nil {
        navigationItem.searchController = searchController
    }
}
```

Edit: I was overly optimistic. On iOS 15.2 this method stopped working for me. What I did to fix it was to move the code after reloading my table/collection view.

Comment: I couldn't get the desired behavior even when I sequenced the searchBar setup after the collectionView reload. I finally got it working by delaying the searchBar setup using DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1).

Answer (score 1):

This is what works for me. I have a UISegmentedControl that reloads the tableView when filter changes.

With FRC:

```
guard let count = try? fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext.count(for: request) else { return }
```

called after tableView.reloadData()

```
navigationItem.searchController = count > 20 ? searchController : nil
```

Answer (score 0):

I find this works:

`self.searchController.searchBar.hidden = YES;`

You will need to unhide at the appropriate time.

Comment: I guess in some way it would work. But I don’t thin it is like in Mail app where the bar appears animated on scroll down

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make this work by setting `isTransculent` `false` on the `navigationBar` and having initial data on `UITableView` or `UICollectionView`. If you have 0 cells initially and trigger `reloadData` after some time (maybe a network call), SearchBar is visible initially. So have a dummy cell or something similar initially and load the data later, if that's the case for you.

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
```

Answer (score 0):

One should set `searchController` after `tableView` gets frame

```
override func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    super.scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView)

    if !scrollView.frame.isEmpty, navigationItem.searchController == nil {
        navigationItem.searchController = searchController
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

**Swift 5.2 & iOS 13.3.1:-**

Try like this. It works fine

```
        navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
```

Comment: Have you tried? According to documentation it doesn’t work like that: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationitem/2897296-hidessearchbarwhenscrolling